# Issue with nextSequenceToken for the PutLogEvents API (AWS Cloudwatch logs)

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

I am facing below error while trying to use AWS API for cloudwatch; the error is coming when i am trying to call: put_log_events.
Bit of context: these are organizational cloud trail logs and i am trying to create log group for each account (using kinesis stream for subscribing).

```py
import base64
import gzip
import json
import logging
import os

import boto3

# Setup logging configuration
logging.basicConfig()
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

logs_client = boto3.client('logs', region_name=os.getenv('AWS_REGION'))

# setting environment variables
global seq_token

def unpack_kinesis_stream_records(event):
    # decode and decompress each base64 encoded data element
    return [gzip.decompress(base64.b64decode(k["kinesis"]["data"])).decode('utf-8') for k in event["Records"]]


def decode_raw_cloud_trail_events(cloudTrailEventDataList):
    # Convert Raw Event Data List
    eventList = [json.loads(e) for e in cloudTrailEventDataList]

    # Filter out-non DATA_MESSAGES since we only require cloud watch message type = DATA_MESSAGE
    filteredEvents = [
        e for e in eventList if e["messageType"] == 'DATA_MESSAGE']

    # Covert each individual log Event Message
    events = []
    for f in filteredEvents:
        for e in f["logEvents"]:
            events.append(
                {
                    'timestamp': e["timestamp"],
                    'message': e["message"],
                }
            )

    events.sort(key=lambda x: x["timestamp"])
    logger.info("{0} Event Logs Decoded".format(len(events)))

    log_group = ("log_group_for_cloudtrail_"+eventList[0]["logStream"].split("_")[1])

    log_stream = os.getenv('AWS_LAMBDA_LOG_STREAM_NAME')

    # creating log group
    try:
        logs_client.create_log_group(
            logGroupName=log_group,
            tags={
                'Created By': 'ZH Lamda'
            }
        )
    except logs_client.exceptions.ResourceAlreadyExistsException:
        print("log group exists")

    try:
        logs_client.create_log_stream(
            logGroupName=log_group,
            logStreamName=log_stream,
        )
    except logs_client.exceptions.ResourceAlreadyExistsException:
        print("log stream already exists")

    return [log_group, log_stream, events]


def handle_request(event, context):
    seq_token = None
    # Unpack Kinesis Stream Records
    kinesis_data = unpack_kinesis_stream_records(event)
    # Decode and filter events
    events = decode_raw_cloud_trail_events(kinesis_data)

    if len(events[2]) == 0:
        return f'No events to process'

    log_event = {
        'logGroupName': events[0],
        'logStreamName': events[1],
        'logEvents': events[2],
    }

    if seq_token is not None:
        log_event['sequenceToken'] = seq_token

    response = logs_client.put_log_events(**log_event)
    seq_token = response['nextSequenceToken']

    return f"Successfully processed {len(events)} records."


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return handle_request(event, context)
```

I can see below error in cloud watch logs:

```
[ERROR] InvalidSequenceTokenException: An error occurred (InvalidSequenceTokenException) when calling the PutLogEvents operation: The given sequenceToken is invalid. The next expected sequenceToken is: null
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 120, in lambda_handler
    return handle_request(event, context)
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 107, in handle_request
    response = logs_client.put_log_events(**log_event)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 391, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 719, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
```

Comment: Are you showing us ALL of your code? The `seq_token` variable is not being initialized, so the `if` statement should fail before it gets to call `put_log_events()`.

Comment: updated to full code.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the Lambda function being invoked multiple times. If so, then the problem is due to `global seq_token`, which only initializes the value of the variable **the first time the function is invoked**.

On *future* invocations, the `seq_token` is already set from the previous run, and is never reset to None. As a result, when `put_log_events()` is next called, the `if` statement is setting a sequence value from an old execution.

To fix all this, initialize the `seq_token` variable within the `handle_request()` function rather than making it global.

Comment: still the same: 
[ERROR] InvalidSequenceTokenException: An error occurred (InvalidSequenceTokenException) when calling the PutLogEvents operation: The given sequenceToken is invalid. The next expected sequenceToken is: 49621767087109290487851963246818297397718434598539494274
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 118, in lambda_handler
 return handle_request(event, context)
File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 105, in handle_request
 response = logs_client.put_log_events(**log_event
File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 391

Comment: Then add a debug line to show the value of `seq_token` before calling `put_log_events`, and also after calling it. It's your code -- you just need to figure out what it's doing wrong.